# Leaps() or AIC for model selection

Tags: r, model-selection, aic

I am deciding how many predictors to include in my model - I currently have 4.
When I use the `leaps()` function, the smallest value for the residual standard error is the three predictor model but when I use `stepAIC`, it's the two predictor model. Which should I rely on and why?

Comment: can you please provide an output of the two? which values are you referring to? R square adjusted, F-statistic or what?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it now

Comment: Try to read some more under the `model-selection` tag here in CV. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-selection

Comment: I've trawled the internet but I can't find anything that really answers my question - leaps or AIC?

Comment: What is your criterion for preference? Only residual standard error? Note that you can't really compare residual standard error if the number of predictors differ. Further note that dozens of posts here have answers pointing to the numerous problems with these kinds of approaches to model choice.

Comment: Why not keep all four? [This is meant seriously -- why do you want to (or think you should) take some out? What are you trying to accomplish?]